# Are there any naming conventions for filenames?

Tags: nativescript

I'm new to nativescript and tried to open a modal.
Everything works fine if I use a filename like "connect-modal-page".

But if I use "connect" only I get the message:
JS ERROR Error: NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Error: Failed to load component from module: ./views/modals/connect.xml

So I guess there is something like a naming convention. But which?
The docs says there isn't any real convention.

Did I miss something?

This filename works:
connect-modal-page.xml

These filenames do not work:
connect-modal.xml
connect.xml

Comment: What you have inside connect.xml, are you embedding the component in another XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using NativeScript and bundling with Webpack (with the upcoming version this will be the default workflow). The thing is that Webpack needs to "know" about any resources that need to be bundled.

So to resolve this issue by design the NativeScript team has provided a pattern that will automatically bundle all pages that are ending with `-page` or `-root`. Any other resource that you want to become part of the bundle should be explicitly included in the `webpack.config.js` file (in the `CopyWebpackPlugin` section). So with NativeScript 5.x.x you will need to either rename all your files to end with `-page` or to add them explicitly in the webpack configuration. Note that I am talking about a project for NativeScript Core (plain JavaScript or TypeScript) and not NativeScript Angular.

From **NativeScript 6** (upcoming release expected in mid-July2019) this won't be needed anymore and all *.xml and *.ts resources (talking about NativeScript Core) will be bundled by default.